# Formatting output of R dataframe

Tags: r

So i currently have a dataframe in R and I want to export/write it to a text file using **write.table()**

Here's an example of the dataframe:

```
ID      FirstName     LastName             Class
1000    John            NA                  C-02
1001    Jane            Wellington          C-03
1002    Kate            NA                  C-04
1003    Adam            West                C-05
```

I want to write it to a text file where for each row, if any column value is NA, then it won't include the word "NA" but proceed to the other column. The output I want:

```
1000    John      C-02
1001    Jane      Wellington      C-03
1002    Kate      C-04
1003    Adam      West       C-05
```

Example as shown, the first row didn't have a last name entered, so I will proceed to the next column, preventing something like:

```
1000    John      NA      C-02
```

I did the write.table() command:

```
write.table(df, "student_list.txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep="\t")
```

But the problem is I'm getting the one where NA is included in the second output i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

dta <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~FirstName, ~LastName, ~Class,
  1000, "John", NA, "C-02",
  1001, "Jane", "Wellington", "C-03",
  1002, "Kate", NA, "C-04",
  1003, "Adam", "West", "C-05"
)

dta %>%
  unite(column, everything(), sep = "  ") %>%
  mutate(column = str_remove_all(column, "NA  ")) %>%
  write.table("student_list.txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` to remove the `NA`s and convert rows into text lines (using `paste`), as follows:

```
data <- apply(df, 1, function(row){
  paste(row[!is.na(row)], collapse="\t")
})

write.table(data, "student_list.txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep="\t")
```

File output would look like the following:

```
#1000   John    C-02
#1001   Jane    Wellington  C-03
#1002   Kate    C-04
#1003   Adam    West    C-05
```